# How to check is string correct to convert it to int?

Tags: c++, string, int

Now I talk only about stl functions. Not something like this:

```
for (char c : s) {
  if (c < '0' || c > '9') {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget [`isdigit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit).

Comment: Do you need to accommodate negative values?

Comment: @tadman, no, I needn't.

Comment: You can try `strtol` and checking the errno

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a built in function that does this, but you can use an algorithm to do this:

```
bool is_valid_int(const std::string& s)
{
    return std::all_of(std::begin(s), std::end(s), 
                         [](unsigned char c) { 
                           return std::isdigit(c); 
                       });
}
```

Note that this solution only checks if all the characters of a string are digits. To check whether it's convertible to an int, you could do something like:

```
int n;
try { n = std::stoi(s); }
catch(...) { /* do something */ }
```

Comment: this will allow leading zeros, which might be ok

Comment: Leading zeroes should be fine. It won't take care of negative `int`s but OP seems ok with that.

Comment: Just because a `string` contains all digit chars doesn't guarantee it will successfully convert to an `int`. It may contain more digits than an `int` can handle. Actually converting the `string` to `int` via `stoi()` or `strtol()` or equivilent, and checking that conversion for failure, is the best option.

Comment: @RemyLebeau true, added that option. Less fun than the algorithm though ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert with `strtol` and then check if the whole string was consumed, e.g.:

```
bool string_is_valid(std::string s)
{
    char const *startptr = s.c_str();
    char *endptr;
    strtol(startptr, &endptr, 10);

    return endptr - startptr == s.size();
}
```

The `endptr` is always set whether or not conversion succeeds.

If it is important to distinguish values that are correct for `long` but out of range for `int` then you would need to store the return value of `strtol` and test it against `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN`.

This option differs from `std::stoi` in that the latter does not give any information about whether there were other trailing characters after a valid number (e.g. `3x` and `3` both would return `3`).